# Is there a good text editor for VHDL(GHDL)?

Tags: software-recommendation, apt, text-editor

I would appreciate very much if someone could recommend me a good text editor for VHDL.

Answer (score 4):

The absolute easiest way to go would be gedit with plugins (specifically, the code snippet plugin)

`sudo apt-get install gedit gedit-plugins`

gedit has the benefit of working well with GHDL.

Emacs (which should come pre-installed on your machine) has a very useful VHDL mode documented [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VhdlMode).

If you want something more full-featured, [Scriptum](http://www.hdlworks.com/products/scriptum/index.html) is very full-featured and comes with support for other languages such as Verilog, C/C++, and Xilinx UCF. Its download page is [here](http://www.hdlworks.com/downloads/scriptum_form.html). (You have to fill out a form, but it's free and doesn't require a license.)

Answer (score 3):

For the record, I've been working on a VHDL syntax checking plugin for Vim called [vim-hdl](https://github.com/suoto/vim-hdl) and it supports GHDL. You can check it out on [github](https://github.com/suoto/vim-hdl)

Answer (score 1):

Vim includes a syntax file for VHDL by default.

Although a little tough to understand at first once you get used to it there are few editors faster or more useful than VIM.

You can install it by running `sudo apt-get install vim-nox` or if you want it with the small gtk shell `sudo apt-get install vim-gtk`.

Be sure to run `vimtutor` if this is your first time using `vim`, it will help you get up to speed on how vim is used. Alternativly you could take a look at [this](http://www.openvim.com/tutorial.html)  online vim tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You're opening [pandora's box here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war)! Most editors will support syntax coloring for a wide range of languages, including VHDL. So your question could be re-interpreted as a question for just a nice editor.

Specifically for VHDL however, Emacs, VI, Notepad++ and UltraEdit are very popular as editors. See [this poll](http://www.vhdleditor.com/poll) and [this poll](http://www.sigasi.com/content/neither-vi-nor-emacs-are-most-popular-vhdl-editor). There's not Notepad++ for Linux, though (afaik).

Answer (score 1):

My personal choice is [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/). You will have to add a package for Verilog and VHDL but it is very easy and Sublime Text includes modern features such as multicursor.